# How do I disable double-click drag in Ubuntu?

Tags: mouse, input-devices

I can find an option in the mouse settings to bring the drag and drop time threshold to very small, which helps with accidental events, but I can't find an option to disable it all together.

Comment: You ever do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old thread but I'll see if I can answer it here. I just got myself a Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 20.04 and the new Gnome UI doesn't have an interface. If yours does, the simple way is to check the touchpad settings and disable click to drag. If it doesn't what you should do is look for your xinput properties:

```
$ xinput list
```

You should see output like this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL096D:01 06CB:CDE6 Mouse                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL096D:01 06CB:CDE6 Touchpad             id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 4943 Finger touch               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

In my case, the correct ID is 13 so lets look at those props:

```
$  xinput list-props 13
```

Again, output looks like this:

```
Device 'DLL096D:01 06CB:CDE6 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (148):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (150): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (321): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (322): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (323):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (324):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (325):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (326):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (327):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (328):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (305):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (306):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (329):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (330):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (307):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (308):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (309):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (331): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (332):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (333):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (334):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (335):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (312): 0.301471
    libinput Accel Speed Default (313): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (317): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (318): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (268): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (269):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (270):    0, 0
    Device Node (271):  "/dev/input/event10"
    Device Product ID (272):    1739, 52710
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (319):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (320):   1
```

In my case, you can see it's property 323 which is called libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (323): 1. The value of 1 means it's on. So your goal is to turn that off. It's easier to use the names to do that. You'll grab the name of the device the the property within it and finally set it to 0. For me, that's

```
$ xinput set-prop "DLL096D:01 06CB:CDE6 Touchpad" "libinput Tapping Drag Enabled" 0
```

Comment: I didn't expect an answer all these years later! Thanks!